# Split User input into different Variables

Tags: python

I'd like to take a user input (like an IP Address) and split the parts into separate variables

for example

255.255.255.0

Now, I would like to split the string by the decimal points and save each part to its own variable. 255 into variable1,
2nd 255 into variable2, 3rd 255 to variable3 and 0 to 
variable 4 as integers.

How can I do this?

Comment: You may also want to use regex to ensure that the initial string is in IPv4 address format.

Answer (score 5):

You could do:

```
a, b, c, d = input().split(".")
```

The `split()` method, by default, splits a string at each space into a list.  But, if you add the optional argument, it will split a string by that character/string.  You can read more about it at the official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

You can also check to make sure the input is in proper IPv4 format.

```
if re.match("\d+[.]\d+[.]\d+[.]\d+", input()):
    print("IPv4 format")
```

Answer (score 1):

might want to add the following to filter for a valid IP:

```
while(1):
    IP=raw_input("Enter an IP Address:")
    if re.search("\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}",IP):
        break
    else:
        print"Invalid Format!"
variable1, variable2, variable3, variable4 = IP.split(".")
```